# Installing M2Crypto inside of virtualenv without installing swig to the system

Tags: python, macos, virtualenv, swig, m2crypto

I am working in a virtual environment and when I pip install M2Crypto on a machine that happens to have swig installed (system-wide) then it installs fine. I need to get M2Crypto to install when swig may not be available system wide though. Is there a way to install M2Crypto in the virtual environment using a local swig install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in the end I got this to work by letting buildout handle downloading and installing swig and M2Crypto and then just moving the built M2Crypto and EGG-INFO directories from where buildout put them to where virtualenv wanted them...this might not be the optimal solution, but hey, it worked.